# Can Saxon XSLT processor be used with the XMLControl in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

The title pretty much says, it - Is it possible to use the Saxon XSLT Processor to be used along with the XMLControl in ASP.NET?

If not, are there any approaches, whereby I can insert a transformed HTML content (using Saxon XSLT processor), within an already existing ASPX page?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Web XML control, which will use Saxon to process XSLT.